# Call asynchronosuly two functions

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

This a php script.I need to download a file using php code.

The zip file can be accessed via a http path.The size is around 400 mb+.Currently i use copy command to save the file(this file lies in another server which is accessed through eg- http://sample.com/myzip.zip) which to local machine.But since its a large file the browser timeouts causing the page to output a blank page after 4-5 minutes.

Can i over come this with jquery using async?

Or can i do parallel processing using php.Please help?

If so could you guide me with a demo please?

Thanks in adv and waiting for the replyy.:)

Comment: Your question is confusing. How are you using a "copy command" in "the browser"? My browser just opens a "Save File" dialog when I click on a link. I can't execute commands in it. Please edit your question and clarify your problem.

Comment: We need some more info on the purpose of your script. You really don't want to be running any PHP script that takes 4-5 minutes through the browser. Could it by run by cron/background job, or through the command line?

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks for you reply.Well i do have the same script running using cron and it works fine.But i have to do it using GUI interface also.
Thats y...Any help on this??

Answer (score 2):

http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1jo517/multithreading_in_php_with_pthreads/

As I discussed in the first few lines of that post, PHP **IS** thread safe.

**NOTHING HAPPENS IN A SYNCHRONOUS WAY, AT ALL**

**YES, IS IT POSSIBLE TO MAKE ASYNCHRONOUS FUNCTION CALLS IN PHP**

Multi-threading is not going to help the OP here, so I have nothing to say; but the answer that @Ngm AKumar gave was incorrect in every way.